# Vertical Center Element in 75% container with other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container with 100% height of window. In this container I have another two smaller containers. One with 75% height, and one with 25% height.

In first 75% height container I have navigation (Logo and Links) with padding of 60px:

```
// Container
header > .slider {
  background-image: url("../images/SliderBG.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 75%;
}

// Navigation
header > .slider > .navigation {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Under this navigation I have one Bootstrap Panel:

```
<div class="container code-editor">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel Content...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It is horizontaly centered. But now I want to center it verticaly, and when I give 100% height to container of Panel it goes under parent container for 60px.

EDIT:

Adding `transform: translateY(50%);` on `header > .slider > .code-editor` partially fixed problem. Now panel is centered verticaly just like I wanted, but when I resize window text makes panel higher and it won't center verticaly like when not resized. It goes bottom and pushs other elements.

Comment: Could you create a demo? It is quite possible you can center it vertically using the css property transform.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz Transform centered it very well, but when I resieze and text makes panel haight greather it won't center again, it goes to bottom